# How can live video be streamed from an iOS device to a server?

Tags: ios, swift, http-live-streaming

I want to be able to stream live video from an iOS device to a server. I tried to use an `AVCaptureOutput` that captures each frame as a `CMSampleBuffer` and appends it using an `AVAssetWriter`, but I don't know when or how to take the input from the file and send it to the server. How should it be formatted? How do I know when to send it?

Comment: For that purpose, there are many 3rd party solutions. In our app we use the  solution provided by http://www.emoze.com/ and it works well (but it costs, and you will have to contact them through their site to get the package)

Comment: Maybe a long shot, but in iOS 9 Apple introduced something called ReplayKit and in iOS 10 they have announced support for live streaming in ReplayKit. I haven't used this myself so I don't know much about it, but maybe it could be useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though i am not sharing any code with you, I am sharing my logic with you what i have done in one of my app.

**First way(The easy one):** There are lots of low cost third party library available for your use.

**Second way(The hard one):** Create small chunk of video for example 2sec or less, keep them in queue and upload it on the server(don't use `afnetworking` or `http` method it will slow down the process use some chat server like `node.js` or other). And keep one text file or db entry where you keep the track of the chunk file and its sequence. And once your first chunk is uploaded you can use `ffmpg` to make a video from the actual chunk, the more chunk you got add them in the main video file, and if you play the actual video on the device you don't have to do any more modification it will automatically fetch the new part once it is changed on the server.

Thank You. Hope it helps you.

Comment: It seems to be how most large scale live streams do it, just keep sending chunks of data to the server, and have the server spit it back to other clients, where it would be put together.

Comment: Yes, But in my case we put together those chunks on the server not on the device. As it is very much difficult to marge those chunks to a main video in the iOS device, and if we play those one after another there is a slight change in frame between the chunks and it was very much noticeable.

Comment: Makes sense! I guess you could do it either way?