# FFmpeg video encoding from iPhone to URL

Tags: swift, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I ran into a problem - I'm building an app, which I would like to be able to livestream. I have found a supplier, that I want to use - "all" he needs me to do, is to encode the video from the camera, to ffmpeg, and call his API. The thing is, I have no clue how to encode the video to ffmpeg. I have tried several google searches, and lots of different SDK's for videostreaming, but it doesnt seem to help in my case.

I know about Wowza and other livestream providers, but they cant deliver what I want, so I think this is my last option.
So if any of you guys out there, can help me with encoding video from the camera into ffmpeg and send it to a API, please let me know how :-)
It could be, that there's a pod out there that i've overseen..

Thanks in advance,
/Nicolai

Comment: As far as I know ffmpeg is a server side technology, you send the video to the API it is then encoded to you whatever format that you require.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960571/how-can-live-video-be-streamed-from-an-ios-device-to-a-server

Comment: Thanks for your comment! In the link youre posting, a person named souvickcse suggests to use some 3rd party libs - du you have any idea about which? Maybe its because I'm searching for the wrong thing.. Its just the guy with the servers, that told med that I needed to send him ffmpeg encoded video, for him to push it to other clients :/

Comment: I'd go back to the server guy, and ask him what he means, I'm not sure whether he has given you misleading information or maybe you have misunderstood what he needs. I'm not up on third party libraries sry.